# Format TextWatcher android

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

My `FourDigitCardFormatWatcher` add a space after every 4 numbers.  I want to change the `FourDigitCardFormatWatch` to the following format 55555 5555 555 55.

How can i determine after 5 numbers add a space, then after 4 digits add a space and after 3 digits add a space.

Actual result: 4444 4444 4444

Expected result: 44444 4444 444

Comment: Maybe you should process the entire text (using regex `^……$`) rather than dealing with substrings.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Obviously you only have to change your `replaceAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the class like this..

```
public class FourDigitCardFormatWatcher implements TextWatcher {

// Change this to what you want... ' ', '-' etc..
private final String char = " ";
EditText et_filed;


public FourDigitCardFormatWatcher(EditText et_filed){
    this.et_filed = et_filed;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String initial = s.toString();
    // remove all non-digits characters
    String processed = initial.replaceAll("\\D", "");

    // insert a space after all groups of 4 digits that are followed by another digit
    processed = processed.replaceAll("(\\d{5})(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(?=\\d)(?=\\d)(?=\\d)", "$1 $2 $3 ");

    //Remove the listener
    et_filed.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    //Assign processed text
    et_filed.setText(processed);

    try {
        et_filed.setSelection(processed.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    //Give back the listener
    et_filed.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
}
```

To add the listener

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new FourDigitCardFormatWatcher(editText1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `replaceAll` statement like below:

```
processed = processed.replaceAll("(\\d{5})(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(?=\\d)*", "$1 $2 $3 ");
```

This kind of worked for me, you may need to change it to suit your requirement.

That should help you, I hope!